# What is $C_{pk}$(test) $-\ C_{pk}$(reference)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have a process under test (approximately normal distributed), and I have calculated [$C_{pk}$ (a process capability index)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_capability_index) for this process. These values are compared to reference values which are of the same process under some condition, and its $C_{pk}$ is present.

What do I get when I subtract: $C_{pk}$(test) $-\ C_{pk}$(reference)?

Comment: Hope I defined "cpk" with the right Wikipedia link; please edit to clarify if not.

Comment: Cpk = MIN [  (μ - LL) / 3 sigma , (HL - μ)  / 3 sigma ] sigma here is robust sigma ie sigma=[(p90-p10)/2.56]

Answer (score 0):

The result would be something akin to the index $C_{p-}$, which was discussed by Roth in 2005 (G. Roth II, "Capability Indexes: Mystery Solved' in *Six Sigma Forum Magazine*).  $$\hat{C}_{p-}=\hat{C}_{p}-\hat{C}_{pk}$$  The theory of the index is that as the values of the potential best case and factoring in the value for $k$ converge, the difference between the PCIs should reduce to 0, indicating a more capable process.  Based on the equations that create $k$, $C_{p-}$ will become 0 whenever $\hat{\mu}$ and the target value are the same and they are centered between the $LSL$ and $USL$.  For example, if $LSL = -2$, $USL = 3$, $\hat{\sigma} = 3$, and $T=\hat{\mu} = 0.5$, then $\hat{C}_{p}$ and $\hat{C}_{pk}$ would both be $.2\overline{7}$ (very poor capability scores) while $\hat{k}$ and $C_{p-}$ would both be 0.  Alternately, using $\hat{k}$, it can be demonstrated that whenever $\hat{\mu}$ is equal to the midpoint of the $LSL$ and $USL$, then $\hat{k}=0$ and $C_{p-}=0$.

Sadly, a comparison of the same index against the reference would leave you with little information about where the process has changed, while tracking the process capability over time can be very beneficial(David Banks, "Is Industrial Statistics Out of Control?" *Statistical Science* (1993).).

For a more meaningful result, you may want to compare the relationship between the [confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233599/how-to-conduct-a-capability-analysis-by-calculating-cpk-and-check-results-usin/243882#243882) of $C_{pk}$(test) and $C_{pk}$(reference).